# I need to compare two csv files using pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, comparison

The output spark dataframe should contain all the rows from both dataframes and a new column(Boolean named common_row) .This column will be true or false based on the equality of the row.

```
Csv1
---
Name
John

Csv2
-----
Name
Arun

Df3
------
#Name# ##Name## ###Common_Row###
John. Arun False
```

Comment: Do you always have 1 name in the csv1 or csv2?  If not, what do you expect to have in Df3 if there are more than 1 name in either of csvs?

Comment: The records in the dataframe are ordered by one column say I'd.If there are more than one name it should show the difference row by row and show the additional column with result

Comment: There is a fundamental reason that column-wise concat is not available in Pyspark. Pyspark dataframe is unordered, so you cannot guarantee to do row by row concat.

If you would like to do that, I would suggest you to add row number to original csv before loading into the dataframe.  Then, use inner join to join the two csvs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below logic -

**Input Data**

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data = [('John',)], schema = ['Name',])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data = [('Arun',)], schema = ['Name',])
```

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

(df2.join(df1, df2['Name'] == df1['Name'], how = 'full')).select(last(df1["Name"]).alias("df1_Name"),first(df2["Name"]).alias("df2_Name")).withColumn("Common_Row", lit(False)).show()

#Output 

+--------+--------+----------+
|df1_Name|df2_Name|Common_Row|
+--------+--------+----------+
|    John|    Arun|     false|
+--------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: Will this apply if I am using multiple rows and multiple columns to compare.Apologise for rephrasing my question

Comment: What's exact use case ? Can you share sample input dataset ?